# Is there a noun for "someone who has access"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

I'm building a data model for a computer program, and I'm in need a noun (a short compound noun is acceptable) for "someone who has access".

The information will be provided as an answer to the question: "Who has access to the data within your company?".

My initial thought was to go with something along the lines of "internal data accessor", but accessor doesn't seem to be a common English word, and it's usage in computer programming doesn't quite match what I'm describing.

Comment: This may be difficult to get down to one noun or name. Would two or three words be acceptable? If a term such as "authorized user" be acceptable, please edit the question to allow for more than one word.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! It wasn't my intention to limit the answers to "a single word". I've update the question to make it more clear that compound nouns are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use "authorized users" to refer to people who have access to a system.

Comment: This is a noun phrase.

Comment: You're a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

'**Privileged User**' seems to be what the software security companies are calling them :

> Top 10 Ways to Identify and Detect Privileged Users

[Stealthbits](https://blog.stealthbits.com/top-10-ways-to-identify-and-detect-privileged-users)

Answer (score 0):

In law, specifically in premises liability, there is a set of words describing various levels of authorization a person might have to enter upon land of another: trespasser, licensee, and invitee.  Putting it simply, a trespasser enters without permission of the other, a licensee enters with permission of the other but to benefit himself, and an invitee enters with permission but to benefit the other.  I am a licensee when you invite me to come onto your land/house for a social event.  (I am your guest.)  But I am an invitee when I go into the Apple Store, because Apple has granted me permission impliedly, and because Apple stands to benefit financially from my presence in its Apple Store.

You could analogize and call the "internal data accessor" an *invitee* or create a neologism, such as *admittee.*

Answer (score -1):

possibly the word you are looking for is permission or privileges:

*One could have **permission** to the data*

or

*One could have data access **privileges***

> **permission:** consent; authorization.
>
> **privilege:** a special right, advantage, or immunity granted or available only to a particular person or group of people.

source: http://www.dictionary.com/

Comment: Permission is used with a verb...permission to view/access/other. Sounds very awkward otherwise.Privileges works.